# Selenium Grid and TestNG, how to make a good use of it

Tags: java, selenium, testng, selenium-grid

I made a test configuration to execute the same test 3 time in parallel.
It's some kind of load testing but there is some point i'm not undertsanding in the configuration of the nodes of Selenium Grid.
Hub command :

> java -jar "c:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -port 4444 -role hub -nodeTimeout 1000

Node command :

> java -jar "C:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=3,maxSession=3 -port 5555

Here is my first problem, when i set the maxInstances and the maxSession, i thought it was what will allow me to execute 3 firefo browser on the node. But even if i put 1 for maxInstances and maxSession, i still can run the 3 browser at the same time when i run my script. I guess my configuration is used the wrong way...
[Display of my console Grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3XSry.png)

To run the test in parallel i used the parellel configuration of TestNG, here my xml file :

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
      <suite name="Suite" parallel="tests">
  <test name="Test0">
  <parameter name="node" value="http://192.168.117.135:5555/wd/hub"/>
  <parameter name="fullName" value="UserFullName0"/>
  <parameter name="firstName" value="UserFirstName"/>
  <parameter name="name" value ="UserName"/>
  <parameter name="init" value ="init"/>
  <parameter name="login" value ="UserLogin"/>
  <parameter name="civility" value="civility"/>
  <parameter name="forcePasswordChange" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="passwordControlModel" value ="pwdModel"/>
  <parameter name="backUpMail" value ="backUpMail@email.com"/>
  <parameter name="language" value ="fr"/>
  <parameter name="externalUser" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="service" value ="service"/>
  <parameter name="company" value ="company"/>
  <parameter name="emailCompany" value ="emailCompany@memail.com"/>
  <parameter name="contributorTest1" value ="contributor"/>
  <parameter name="lockedByAdministration" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="multisessions" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="invisibleAccount" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="isAlive" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="expirationDate" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="role" value ="role"/>
  <parameter name="autorizedConnection" value ="55"/>
  <parameter name="authentificationPolicy" value ="LOCAL"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="selenium.test.UserSaveTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="Test1">
  <parameter name="node" value="http://192.168.117.135:5555/wd/hub"/>
  <parameter name="fullName" value="UserFullName1"/>
  <parameter name="firstName" value="UserFirstName"/>
  <parameter name="name" value ="UserName"/>
  <parameter name="init" value ="init"/>
  <parameter name="login" value ="UserLogin"/>
  <parameter name="civility" value="civility"/>
  <parameter name="forcePasswordChange" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="passwordControlModel" value ="pwdModel"/>
  <parameter name="backUpMail" value ="backUpMail@email.com"/>
  <parameter name="language" value ="fr"/>
  <parameter name="externalUser" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="service" value ="service"/>
  <parameter name="company" value ="company"/>
  <parameter name="emailCompany" value ="emailCompany@memail.com"/>
  <parameter name="contributorTest1" value ="contributor"/>
  <parameter name="lockedByAdministration" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="multisessions" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="invisibleAccount" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="isAlive" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="expirationDate" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="role" value ="role"/>
  <parameter name="autorizedConnection" value ="55"/>
  <parameter name="authentificationPolicy" value ="LOCAL"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="selenium.test.UserSaveTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
  <test name="Test2">
  <parameter name="node" value="http://192.168.117.135:5555/wd/hub"/>
  <parameter name="fullName" value="UserFullName2"/>
  <parameter name="firstName" value="UserFirstName"/>
  <parameter name="name" value ="UserName"/>
  <parameter name="init" value ="init"/>
  <parameter name="login" value ="UserLogin"/>
  <parameter name="civility" value="civility"/>
  <parameter name="forcePasswordChange" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="passwordControlModel" value ="pwdModel"/>
  <parameter name="backUpMail" value ="backUpMail@email.com"/>
  <parameter name="language" value ="fr"/>
  <parameter name="externalUser" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="service" value ="service"/>
  <parameter name="company" value ="company"/>
  <parameter name="emailCompany" value ="emailCompany@memail.com"/>
  <parameter name="contributorTest1" value ="contributor"/>
  <parameter name="lockedByAdministration" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="multisessions" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="invisibleAccount" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="isAlive" value ="true"/>
  <parameter name="expirationDate" value ="false"/>
  <parameter name="role" value ="role"/>
  <parameter name="autorizedConnection" value ="55"/>
  <parameter name="authentificationPolicy" value ="LOCAL"/>
    <classes>
      <class name="selenium.test.UserSaveTest"/>
    </classes>
  </test> <!-- Test -->
</suite> <!-- Suite -->
```

And the script in java associated :

```
public class UserSaveTest {


  @Parameters("node")
  //@Test(invocationCount = 1)
  @Test(invocationCount = 1, threadPoolSize=1)
  public void checkUserFields(String node) throws InterruptedException, MalformedURLException {
        um.initWebDriver(node);
        um.logIn("root", "pass");
        um.initSave();
        um.save();

        um.logOut();
        um.logIn("root", "pass");

        um.initCheck();
        User user =(User) um.getEntity();
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div/div/textarea", user.getFullName()), user.getFullName());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/input", user.getFirstName()), user.getFirstName());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/input",user.getName()),user.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/input",user.getInit()),user.getInit());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/input",user.getCivility()), user.getCivility());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div/div/div/div/input",user.getLogin()), user.getLogin());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/textarea",user.getPassWordControlModel()), user.getPassWordControlModel());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[7]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/input","password_Test1"), "password_Test1");

        DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");
        Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
        String todaysDate = dateFormat.format(calendar.getTime());

        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[3]/div/div/input", todaysDate), todaysDate);
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findTextAndCompare("//div[10]/div[2]/div[4]/div/div/div/input", user.getAutorizedConnection()),user.getAutorizedConnection());
        Assert.assertEquals(um.findAndCheckMenu("//div[5]/div/div/button", user.getAuthentificationPolicy()),user.getAuthentificationPolicy());
        //fin des champs textuels

        //champs radio
        Assert.assertTrue(um.findAndCheckRadio("//div[2]/div[2]/div/div/label", "//div[2]/div/div[2]/label", false));
        Assert.assertTrue(um.findAndCheckRadio("//div[3]/div/div/label", "//div[3]/div/div[2]/label", true));
        Assert.assertTrue(um.findAndCheckRadio("//div[9]/div[2]/div/div/div/label", "//div[9]/div[2]/div/div/div[2]/label", false));
        Assert.assertTrue(um.findAndCheckRadio("//div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/label", "//div[9]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div[2]/label", false));
        Assert.assertTrue(um.findAndCheckRadio("//div[9]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/label", "//div[9]/div[2]/div[3]/div/div[2]/label", false));
        Assert.assertTrue(um.findAndCheckRadio("//div[4]/div/div/label", "//div[4]/div/div[2]/label", true));
        //fin champs radio

        um.deleteUser();

        um.close();
  }


  //Suppression de l'user et fermeture du driver
  @AfterTest
  public void finishTheTest() {
      um.close();
  }
}
```

Whan i check on the node address i see all the session that i have run and there is more than 3. The scprit is well executed but i want to know why it is working when it isn't supposed to.
If i can execute the 3 instances of my browser at the same time when the maxSession and the maxInstances of my nodes are setted to 1, what are the use of these ?
Thanks

Comment: maxSession is a flag that needs to be set on the **hub** not the **node**.

Comment: @Mobrockers - maxSession is something that is set at the node level and not at the hub level

Comment: @Krishan Ah right, that is true. However he is trying to define it as a capability, instead of a command line flag.

Comment: thanks for your answer, i did the changement in the comment but i still can run multiple browser when i specify only 1 maxSession and 1 maxInstances

Answer (score 1):

Bob,
maxSession -

- maxSession - represents the maximum number of concurrent sessions that can be opened up at any given point in time in a node (its a consolidated value across all browser flavors that the node supports )
- maxInstances - represents the maximum number of concurrent sessions that can be opened up at any given point in time in a node per browser flavor.

Just to ensure that your configurations are being read properly when you start the node, can you please resort to leveraging a JSON configuration file for specifying it and start the node using that ? I am guessing that perhaps the configurations aren't being read properly when you pass it the way you have.

To create a node configuration file, you can create a json file which looks like below

```
{
  "capabilities":
      [
        {
          "browserName": "firefox",
          "maxInstances": 1
        }
      ],
  "configuration":
  {
    "proxy": "org.openqa.grid.selenium.proxy.DefaultRemoteProxy",
    "maxSession": 1,
    "port": 5555,
    "register": true,
    "registerCycle": 5000,
    "hub": "http://localhost:4444"
  }
}
```

Sample borrowed from [here](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/master/java/server/src/org/openqa/grid/common/defaults/DefaultNodeWebDriver.json)

You then alter you node start command to something like below

```
java -jar "C:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -nodeConfig C:\selenium-2.53.0\nodeConfig.json -port 5555
```

here

> C:\selenium-2.53.0\nodeConfig.json

would contain the json content that I have pasted earlier.

Once you start the node in this manner, I think what you expect should happen.

Answer (score 0):

maxSession is a command line flag, not a capablity, so run your node like this instead:

```
java -jar "C:\selenium-2.53.0\selenium-server-standalone-2.53.0.jar" -role node -hub http://localhost:4444/grid/register -browser browserName=firefox,maxInstances=1 -port 5555 -maxSession 1
```